# Utilizar imagenes en Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

Veran, tengo una tabla de plantas:

```
Schema::create('plantas', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('nombre'); // Nombre de la planta.
            $table->string('tamaño'); // Clasifica segun si es arbol, arbusto o hierba. 
            $table->string('flor'); // Si tiene o no flor.
            $table->string('hoja'); // Si es de hoja caduca o perenne.
            $table->text('descripcion'); // Caracteristicas del vegetal.
            $table->string('foto')->nullable(); // Esta variable sera utilizada para almacenar fotos. Es opcional.
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Entre las variables de la planta esta una foto y quiero que en mi formulario se pueda importar la imagen. Para esto, tengo este formulario:

```
<form method="POST" action="../planta"> {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nombre" class="col-md-12 control-label" enctype="multipart/form-data"> {{ __("Nombre") }}
            </label>
            <input id="nombre" class="form-control" name="nombre" value="{{ old('nombre') }}"/>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="tamaño" class="col-md-12 control-label"> {{ __("Tamaño") }}
            </label>
            <input id="tamaño" class="form-control" name="tamaño" value="{{ old('tamaño') }}"/>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="flor" class="col-md-12 control-label"> {{ __("Flor") }}
            </label>
            <input id="flor" class="form-control" name="flor" value="{{ old('flor') }}"/>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="hoja" class="col-md-12 control-label"> {{ __("Hoja") }}
            </label>
            <input id="hoja" class="form-control" name="hoja" value="{{ old('hoja') }}"/>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="descripcion" class="col-md-12 control-label"> {{ __("Descripción") }}
            </label>
            <input id="descripcion" class="form-control" name="descripcion" value="{{ old('descripcion') }}"/>
        </div>

        <label class="btn btn-warning" for="foto">
            <input id="foto" name="foto" type="foto" style="display:none;"> {{ __("Subir imagen (Opcional)") }}
        </label>

        <button type="submit" name="addPlanta" class="btn btn-default"> {{ __("Añadir Planta") }}
        </button>
    </form>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y aqui esta el resultado. Entre las cosas que vereis esta un icono que es para la foto. El problema es que ese botón por más que lo pulso no hace nada.
Parece ser que tendria que ponerlo en modo ***php artisan serve***, pero la verdad es que ese modo esta arisco y no me deja iniciar sesión, cuando no tengo ningun problema de forma normal.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien conoce un modo de salir de esta, por favor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder cargar imagenes con el formulario, el atributo:
**enctype="multipart/form-data"**
has de ponerlo dentro de la etiqueta ***form*** de apertura del formulario:

```
<form method="POST" action="../planta" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Vale, gracias por advertirme de mi fallo. Desafortunadamente, sigue el botón sin reaccionar.

Comment: De nada, creo que el input type="foto" no existe, sería type="file". Saludos.

Comment: Cierto, ya he conseguido que el botón funcione, pero aun no he conseguido que la imagen se muestre en la vista, por lo que he editado mi pregunta para añadir más datos.